# Fast me ring of huge lists

Tags: python, file, merge, large-data

I want to merge 2 > GB sized files. Each file contains in alternating rows identifier and value. Merging means: if the identifier is only found in either file or if it is found in both files and the value is identical: keep the value. If the identifier is found in both files but the value is different, reject it. Identifier and values are both strings.

I know it sounds quite simple but my lack of knowledge in python leads only to solutions which will run very very long. Any hints towards a quicker way would be great.

Comment: Could you provide a brief example of the files and describe your solution so far?

Comment: Seems like a database task. It looks like you could load the files into a database and do a join to efficiently find the non-conflicting values. (Disclaimer: I have never used a database. This may be a bad idea.)

Comment: Are the files sorted?

Comment: what type of files are they? ascii? or some fancy binary format? and what is the internal structure of the file, some more details on that could be useful too, like an example of a few lines or so.